# Reshaping a dataframe keeping only the most recent dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as such:

```
id    date         cc
aa1   01/01/2016   foo
aa1   01/05/2016   foo
aa1   01/09/2016   bar
aa1   01/05/2017   baz
aa2   04/03/2016   foo
aa2   09/04/2017   bar
aa3   02/02/2017   foo
```

I'm trying to create a dataframe as such:

```
id    date_foo     cc_foo     date_bar     cc_bar    date_baz     cc_baz
aa1   01/05/2016   foo        01/09/2016   bar       01/05/2017   baz
aa2   04/03/2016   foo        09/04/2017   bar       null         null
aa3   02/02/2017   foo        null         null      null         null
```

My problem is:
- for `bb_foo` and `cc_foo` I only need the most recent record, as my data can have multiple rows for the same `id

Appreciate any help

Comment: What's the logic behind creation of the second dataframe?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The idea is to get a unique record for each `id` where one row contains all the data required. There are `df.cc.unique()` = [`foo`,`bar`,`baz`]

Comment: I don't see any bb_foo or cc_foo in your sample data. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very close to what you need. You'll need to call `df.groupby` on all but `date`, and then get the most recent value of `date` in `dfGroupBy.agg`, followed by an unstack operation.

```
In [1114]: df.groupby(['id', 'cc']).agg({'date' : lambda x: x.sort_values().drop_duplicates().values[-1] }).unstack()
Out[1114]: 
           date                        
cc          bar         baz         foo
id                                     
aa1  01/09/2016  01/05/2017  01/05/2016
aa2  09/04/2017        None  04/03/2016
aa3        None        None  02/02/2017
```

Instead of separate `cc_xxx` columns, you have all the information in the `MultiIndex`.